# Is it possible to enable an Org Streaming API through Apex?

Tags: package, streaming-api

It really is a simple question, just wasn't able to find such information, and the wide availability of streaming apis across the web doesn't help searching.

I'm trying to know whether we can enable the Streaming API using apex or if it can be enabled via any other way other than through *App Setup -> Custumize -> User Interface -> Setup -> Enable Streaming API*.

The objective is to be able to build a package that could propose the activation and make it without the need to travel the menus.

Any help will be welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately that's not possible.  As a general rule the setup section is foreign territory for APEX.

You're best option at the moment is to add a link to that particular section of the menu from a setup page (or in an email to the installer).  You may also be able to default the box to checked when the page loads with [url hacking](https://www.google.com/search?q=salesforce%20url%20hacking) (although this may not work on setup pages).

Comment: Thanks Ralph, that helped me more than what I was expecting :)